# How many increase

Tags: grammaticality

```
How many increase in the (number of) jobs go to Americans?
```

Is using `How many increase` correct above (instead of `How much increase`)

Answer (score 1):

*Increase* is not a countable noun, so you can't say *how many increase.*

"How many of the increased number of jobs go to Americans?" (*How many* refers to *jobs*)

Answer (score 0):

Neither are correct.  You need to use:

> What increase in the number of jobs goes to America?

Or (depending on your context/meaning);

> What increase in the number of jobs is attributable to America?

“An increase“ is a single concept, with a particular value, and you cannot refer to “many increase” as if it was a plural. Notice that the question focuses on “the increase” (singular) not on “the jobs” (plural).

Comment: The sentence in the question says "Americans" (the group of people), not "America" (the place or country) so this version doesn't really work as an equivalent.